# mouseover - Changing element when sideNav is Open

Tags: html, css

I know I will be kicking myself but..

I have element called open-button which is a little button on the left hand side of the page. Another element called main-side-nav which contains links to other parts of the page.

In theory when the user rolls over it, the nav bar width increases (and appears) and disappear when the user **rolls out of the main side nav**.
Whats happening at the moment is when I roll back out from the button, it closes, instead of rolling back out from the main nav.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var mb = document.getElementById("open-button");
  mb.addEventListener("mouseover", openSideNav);

  var mk = document.getElementById("main-side-nav");
  mk.addEventListener("mouseout", closeSideNav);

  var navBar = document.getElementById("main-side-nav").style;

  function openSideNav() {
    console.log("open");
    navBar.width = "100px";
  }

  function closeSideNav() {
    navBar.width = "0px";
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="open-button"></div>
<div id="main-side-nav" class="sidenav">
  <a href="#section-home">
    <img src="img/links/home.svg" class="image-links" id="image-links-home">
  </a>
  <a href="#section-mystory">
    <img src="img/links/mystory.svg" class="image-links" id="image-links-mystory">
  </a>
  <a href="#section-links">
    <img src="img/links/links.svg" class="image-links" id="image-links-links">
  </a>
```

I hope this makes sense.

Comment: Where is the function `closeSideNav`?

Comment: Apologies, was trying to get it working without it to begin with.

Comment: May need to see html code as well.. You could use css solution if you want only to show/hide in hover https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_sidenav_buttons.asp

Comment: Cant use CSS unfortunately, HTML added.

Comment: Looks like you leaving open-button once you start hovering over main-side-nav, try putting main-side-nav inside open-button div.. Although may be bad practice..

Answer (score 0):

Your JavaScript code is fine your problem with the elements inside the main-side-nav they don't any width value which mean it's setting to default value **auto** if you added to each element the following attribute your code will run correctly :

```
style="width: inherit;"
```

check it below:

```js
  window.onload=function(){
  var mb = document.getElementById("open-button");
  mb.addEventListener("mouseover", openSideNav);

  var mk = document.getElementById("main-side-nav");
  mk.addEventListener("mouseout", closeSideNav);

  var navBar = document.getElementById("main-side-nav").style;

  function openSideNav() {
      console.log("open");
      navBar.width = "100px";
  }
  function closeSideNav() {
      console.log('close');
      navBar.width = "1px";
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="open-button">test</div>
<div id="main-side-nav" class="sidenav" style="width: 0px;">
<a href="#section-home" style="width: inherit;">
<img src="https://www.macupdate.com/images/icons256/57051.png" class="image-links" id="image-links-home" style="width: inherit;">
</a>
<a href="#section-mystory" style="width: inherit;">
<img src="https://www.macupdate.com/images/icons256/57051.png" class="image-links" id="image-links-mystory" style="width: inherit;">
</a style="width: inherit;">
<a href="#section-links" style="width: inherit;">
<img src="https://www.macupdate.com/images/icons256/57051.png" class="image-links" id="image-links-links" style="width: inherit;">
</a>
</div>
```

although am not fan of the current solution you are building but just wanted to explain why your code is not working as you expect.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I haven't had a chance to test this but it makes a hell of a lot of sense. When you said you're not a fan of the code. Can you explain to me how it would be best to code it? Thanks again.

Comment: Thanks for your edit suggestions.. But without the use of jQuery is above best practice? Is there any way of improving it? Thanks once again.

Comment: no it's not good practice to create div and add event Listener just to change the width you can achieve that with poor JavaScript without extra div  or even with CSS without any js code